# Qual é a finalidade dos blocos de comandos vazio ou que não pertencem a algum comando?

Tags: c#, característica-linguagem, sintaxe

Um bloco de comandos é composto de dois ou mais comandos entre chaves `{...//Comandos}`, eu posso usar eles para as seguintes situações que já conheço:

- Em um **if:** `if(codicao){...//Comandos}`.
- Em um **for:** `for(inicializacao; condicao; incremento){...//Comandos}`.
- Em um **while:** `while(codicao){...//Comandos}`.
- Em **funções:** `void fazAlgo(){...//Comandos}`.
- E também em **classes** e outros comandos da linguagem.

No entanto, o C# permite que eu use blocos de comandos para criar escopos sem que seja para as situações acima, ou seja, um bloco de comandos que não pertencem a nenhum dos comandos tradicionais citados acima.

Veja o exemplo criado para ilustrar a situação:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int valor1 = 50;

    { //Inicio do bloco
        int valor2 = 100;
        Console.WriteLine("valor1 no bloco: " + valor1);
        Console.WriteLine("valor2 no bloco: " + valor2);
    } //Fim do bloco

    //Bloco vazio.
    { }    

    Console.WriteLine("valor1 fora bloco: " + valor1);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

No exemplo acima que utilizei para ilustração a um bloco que contem uma variável de tipo inteiro `valor2`, eu gostaria de saber qual é a finalidade de um bloco de comandos como este? E ainda o compilador me permitiu criar um bloco vazio `{ }`, o compilador não acusou nenhum erro correspondente a este bloco vazio, tem alguma utilidade em usar um bloco vazio? Já que ele é permitido pelo compilador.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Como já deu para perceber, a definição do que é um bloco de comando já está errada. Ele permite **zero** ou mais comandos (não gosto muito da tradução de *statement* para comando, mas ela a mais próxima que temos, então aceitável se a pessoa entender bem o que isto significa).

## Método vazio

Se for um método que deve fazer nada dentro, aí tem:

```
public void Exemplo() {}
```

Esse é um método que explicitamente deve fazer nada. É raro ter uma necessidade assim, mas tem sua utilidade. É mais comum em métodos virtuais. Ou o virtual deve fazer nada, mas deixa seus descendentes fazerem ou o que sobrescreve deve eliminar o comportamento do ascendente. Se a opção for esta então deve ser muito bem pensada.

Note que um método vazio é diferente de um método virtual ou parcial sem implementação. O vazio tem uma implementação, que é fazer nada. E se é um erro chamar aquele método que foi obrigado a implementar por algum contrato, como primeira opção pense se deveria usar aquele contrato, e em segunda optar por lançar uma exceção (`NotImplementedException`) para não usá-lo em vez de engolir a execução.

Os puristas dirão que não deve usar a segunda opção, os pragmáticos dirão que não é tão grave fazer isto, ainda mais se tiver alguma ferramenta que ajude detectar isto antes de ir para o *runtime*.

## Bloco vazio

De fato usar o bloco vazio desta forma não tem utilidade. Mas por que deveria dar um erro?

Lembrando que o compilador não tenta ser mais esperto do que ele precisa. Daria muito trabalho para ficar verificando algo que não faz diferença. O compilador tem coisas mais importantes para fazer.

Além disto o máximo que poderia dar é um *warning*, afinal não causa erro algum fazer isto. Mesmo assim seria um exagero, porque mesmo *warnings* devem ser para casos onde tem potencial real para causar problemas. O que leva a dizer que muitos programadores não tratam *warnings* como erros, embora eles sejam, e vão causar problemas. No máximo isto deveria ser objeto de análise estática onde os falsos positivos são esperados.

Eu já peguei um código legado de 120 mil linhas que possuía 600 mil *warnings*. E o código "funcionava" :D

## Novo escopo

O caso do bloco sem estar vinculado ao comando é útil em casos onde precisa introduzir uma variável e mesmo nome, assim fica legível onde já existe outra variável com mesmo nome.

Em geral o código pode ser modificado para evitar isso, mas também não é tão necessário. Muitas vezes quando é necessário significa que o método está complicado demais.

Estas duas variáveis possuem o mesmo nome mas são completamente independentes.

```
{
    {
        int x = 0;
    }

    {
        int x = 0;
    }
}
```

Isso é válido. Já o abaixo não compila porque a variável de um escopo pode estar escondendo a outra:

```
{
    {
        int x = 0;
    }
    int x = 0;
}
```

Faria mais sentido em casos assim:

```
{
    if (true) { //aqui iria uma condição real
        int x = 0;
    }

    {
        int x = 0;
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Syntax/Scope.cs).

Sem o bloco aparentemente desnecessário isto não compilaria. O primeiro `x` poderia estar "sombreando" o segundo. Com o bloco eles se tornam independentes e compila.

Pra falar a verdade, a utilidade disto é algo bastante teórica. Na prática é possível produzir código legível sem ter que se preocupar com isto. Neste caso específico se não existisse este bloco não faria grande falta. Claro que alguns acham que é importante. Vejo tanta coisa que é mais importante e não existe na linguagem.

Comment: Tirei a definição de um livro que tenho aqui sobre C# rsrs

Answer (score 5):

Não, não há nenhuma utilidade em usar o bloco `{}` vazio, ele simplesmente é ignorado pelo compilador, a utilidade dele se dá apenas quando está sendo usado junto a outro comando sendo eles: `if`, `else`,`while`, etc. Mas sozinho é apenas ignorado da mesma forma que o `begin`/`end` é utilizado junto ao `if`, `else` , `while` no Delphi. Se você criar um `begin`/`end` vazio o compilador Delphi também irá compilar normalmente como em C#, pois apenas ignorou o bloco vazio. Espero ter ajudado.